# Xamarin app landscape deployment

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need my app to run in landscape, whether the user has locked their device orientation to portrait, landscape or auto-rotate.

To do this (for Android), I have added `, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.SensorLandscape` into my MainActivity.cs file, which now looks like

```
namespace TabletEPOS.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "TabletEPOS", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.SensorLandscape)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }
}
```

Yet when I test my app using Xamarin Live Player to my phone, it still deploys in portrait.

What do I need to do to get it in landscape?

[image]

Comment: Does it deploy in landscape in a real device/emulator?

Comment: @hichame.yessou the default UWP emulator doesn't deploy it in landscape, I will try with my device plugged in and see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

Check a below code it's should work.

```
namespace TabletEPOS.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "TabletEPOS", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.SensorLandscape)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

             if (Xamarin.Forms.Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet)
             {
             RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape;
             }
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't resolve the issue. I've also added the `if (Xamarin.Forms...` for checking if it's a phone, too, but it still deployed in portrait.

Answer (score 0):

Use ScreenOrientation.Landscape instead of ScreenOrientation.SensorLandscape